# setinterval stop working when I change youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, setinterval

```
zzz=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('bugbox').value = 
player.getCurrentTime()}, 1000);
```

I play the video and I see the time in bugbox

When I click the button the video loads but setInterval don't show player.getCurrentTime(); in bugbox

```
onclick="document.getElementById('player').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=vt4X7zFfv4k'
```

First video is loaded from this code:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
idv='qV5lzRHrGeg';
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: idv,
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
}
```

Edit:
Solved!
I use @NewToJS solution from the comment.

Comment: You're not firing the `setInterval` function

Comment: If you want to get **events** from the youtube player I would recommend using youtubes API.

Comment: It stop when I load the new video in the same iframe

Comment: Try to re-assign `player`, it might be a new object after reload, though as NewToJS said, it's better to use the API.

Comment: you should probably call setInterval in the onclick event as well.

Comment: Oh, you are using the api, why not just change the video id? You don't need to set the src. `player.loadVideoById("Video-ID-Here");` And you can use onPlayerStateChange to call a function to display the current time when the player has loaded the video.